# Make an object follow camera's rotation, towards the center

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, virtual-reality

I have an object, which has the following code:

```
    [SerializeField]
    Transform target;
    [SerializeField]
    Vector3 defaultDistance = new Vector3(0f, 2f, -10f);
    [SerializeField]
    float distanceDamp = 2f;
    [SerializeField]
    Vector3 defaultPos;
    Transform myT;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        myT = transform;
        defaultPos = this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () { 
Vector3 toPos = target.position + (target.rotation * defaultDistance);
        toPos = new Vector3(toPos.x, 1f , toPos.z);
        Vector3 curPos = Vector3.Lerp(myT.position, toPos, distanceDamp * Time.deltaTime);
        myT.position = curPos;
}
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I want the object(cube in this example, but then GUI in VR) to follow Main Camera's rotation, meaning I want the object to Lerp into the center of the camera's view when it rotates. When removing the line of code `toPos = new Vector3(toPos.x, 1f , toPos.z);` and adding the `LookAt` function, If I use a GUI/Cube/etc, it works perfectly, the object is always moving towards the center of the camera. **BUT** - I don't want the object to move towards the center when I rotate my camera Up/Down on the X-Axis. Thus, I wrote that line `toPos = new Vector3(toPos.x, 1f , toPos.z);` and now I have a bug, when I rotate the camera on the X-Axis (Meaning, up/down), after some degrees of X-axis rotation, the object starts moving on Z-Axis towards the camera's position, **Instead** **I don't want it to move at all** when I rotate upwards/downwards.

I have worked it around with eulerAngles, but It's not the solution I'm looking for because I need to define a range of degrees which still makes the object lift a bit up/down. **I want it to move only on circular way around the camera on any rotation.** (I've the circular movement code, but I wasn't able to implement it to my needs above)

Here's the eulerAngles code:

```
if (target.rotation.eulerAngles.x >= 350 || target.rotation.eulerAngles.x <= 10)
{
    Move the object towards the camera's view
    Vector3 toPos = target.position + (target.rotation * defaultDistance);
    Vector3 curPos = Vector3.Lerp(myT.position, toPos, distanceDamp * Time.deltaTime);
    myT.position = curPos;
}
else //Return the object to it's position and Y=1 (goes down/up accordingly to camera)
{
    Vector3 curPos = Vector3.Lerp(myT.position, new Vector3(myT.position.x, 1, myT.position.z), distanceDamp * Time.deltaTime);
    myT.position = curPos;
}
```

EDIT:
This is what I've achieved so far, The cube doesn't center on the middle yet, but it circly rotates around the camera's rotation.

```
 Vector3 toPos = target.position + target.rotation * new Vector3(defaultDistance.x, 0.0f, defaultDistance.z);
        float multiplier = Mathf.Sqrt(defaultDistance.x * defaultDistance.x + (defaultDistance.z) * (defaultDistance.z));
        //multiplier /= Mathf.Sqrt(toPos.x * toPos.x + toPos.z * toPos.z); 
        toPos.x *= -multiplier;
        toPos.y = target.position.y + defaultDistance.y;
        toPos.z *= -multiplier ;
        toPos.z -= 70;

        Vector3 curPos = Vector3.Lerp(myT.position, toPos, distanceDamp * Time.deltaTime);
        myT.position = curPos;
```

EDIT 2:
Almost perfect now with `toPos.z -= 60;`

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want a transform at the center of the viewport but at an offset distance and always facing the camera. Is that correct?

Comment: @MrDos Exactly. take a GUI in front of the screen, always following the camera's view port in the center with some distance because it should be in World Space (Developing for VR environment) and only moving in the Y axis, meaning on XZ plane.

Comment: Still doing problems.. Looking for a solid solution. Because adjusting the z axis like that toPos.z -= 60 won't get things done. Any ideas guys? @MrDos

Answer (score 1):

Would this do the trick?

```
Vector3 targetPos = target.position;
targetPos.y = transform.position.y;
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPos - transform.position);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, 0.5f);
```

Comment: You mean  `Vector3 targetPos = target.position;
        targetPos.y = transform.position.y;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPos - transform.position);`   , Well it doesn't do anything if I remove the previous code in the `LateUpdate()`. Should I keep it?

Comment: Thanks for your input. But it doesn't work with and without the code in my `LateUpdate()`. I also tried to put it before my code and after my code in the function and no changes. The bug remains. Any more suggestions sir.?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS I added the easing and the declaration.
This definitely works for me. Your bug sounds typical of problems when dealing with euler angles...

Comment: Nothing happens. I put the script on the Object. The starting position of the object is Z=10 on the position axis. And when I rotate the camera's view, the object doesn't move at all.

Comment: Updated my post again. Almost perfect now. @MrDos